# How to call action when select noSelectionLabel?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam, selectonemenu

I have this code above which works perfectly when i select some of the items on him... The a4j:support works fine and rerender my another field correctly...
The problem is if i choose one item, and then i back to "noSelectionLabel"...
When i do this for some reason my a4j:support dont work, i dont get into my method "setarFormulario" and i dont rerender my another field...

```
<s:decorate template="layout/form.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="label">Evento:</ui:define>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{home.instance.evento}" required="true">
                <s:selectItems value="#{eventoService.obterTodos()}" var="evento" label="#{messages[evento.nome]}"  noSelectionLabel="#{messages['br.com.message.NoSelection']}" />
                <s:convertEntity  />
                <a4j:support event="onchange"  action="#{home.setarFormulario}" reRender="camposFormulario" ajaxSingle="true"  />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </s:decorate>
```

How can i get into my method even if i select the noSelectionLabel? Then my home.instance.evento must be null.. or something like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yor field `h:selectOneMenu` is required then selecting `noSelectionLabel` value will cause a validation error and if you had validation error, then the `action="#{home.setarFormulario}"` would never be called.

As a workaround you can set to *true* the attribute `hideNoSelectionLabel` for your `s:selectItems` then the noSelectionLabel will be hidden when a value is selected

Comment: Thanks! I've solved before with another workaround... i've putted of "required=true"... Then my setarFormulario method got called... But solving this way u show looks better :) thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
<h:message for="id of the selectonemenu component " ></h:message>
```

or

remove the `required =true` from the `selectonemenu` tag